# Which yeoman version I should install with Node v6.11.2 and npm3.10.10

Tags: node.js, yeoman, spfx

I am trying to setup my first SharePoint framework on SP2016 on-premise. Microsoft indicated only spfx v1.1 is supported. According to some old blog, I need to install Node v6.x for spfx v1.1.

After I install node v6.11.2, I tried to install Yeoman as everyone do.

npm install -g yo

Then I am getting follow error:

```
C:\Users\myuserid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-doctor\lib\index.js:12
  (async () => {
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myuserid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-doctor\lib\cli.js:3:1)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\gulp\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! yo@3.1.0 postinstall: `yodoctor`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@3.1.0 postinstall script 'yodoctor'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the yo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     yodoctor
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs yo
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls yo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I guess I need to install an older version Yo? If so could you advise which one is suitable?